# How to show NSData or base64 coming from server to UIWebView as pdf?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I am getting `base64` data from server and converting it into `NSData` but unable to show it on `webview` (but we know that the data is in `pdf` format).

I tried with this code but not working :

```
[webview loadData:fileData MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: why you reverting the changes i have made in edit ? just approve it.

Comment: vaibhav : please revert again it was by mistake

Comment: okay, i have done again and please clarify more about your ques and show what data you getting from server.

Comment: i am getting base64 from my server.

Comment: May be `baseURL` can not be `nil` as I know. I have the same issue - do you resolve it?